# How to query when data is spread into different microservices?

Tags: database, architecture, microservices

I'm new on microservices architecture and I'm facing this problem:

I have a platform where basically Users manage the accounting of their Clients.

I have one microservice in charge of the security. This one manages which Users have access to which Clients.

Then I have another microservice that manages the Invoices of the Clients.
One of the functions here would be: given a User is logged, list all the Invoices of all the Clients that the User has access to.

For that, I thought that I should ask the Security microservice to give me the list of the Clients the User has access to. And then, I go to the database of Invoices and query, filtering by all those clients.

The problem is that I end up with a horrible query, as it's something like:

SELECT * FROM Invoice WHERE clientId IN (CLI1, CLI2, CLI3, ...) -- Potentially 200 clients

I thought to keep a copy of the User-Client relation in the Invoice database. Or to have both microservices sharing the same database. But none of them convince me as I have more microservices that may face the same problem, leading to a huge repetition of data or to a big monolithic database.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In general, database access is restricted across the services, and also keeping information which you do not own, tends to be a tiresome process as you will always be in fight to sync this piece of data with its intended source of truth.

So the only option that you have is what you have already mentioned in the question.

You end up with a horrible query.

But is it horrible when you write it or will it lag in performance?

It depends, yes if you are using MySQL, you can always perform joins over sub queries

But joins have there own cost.

And even than it will be ok to check if sub queries in these cases gives you expected performance.

If its feasible you can explore other databases which could be really optimized for queries like these.

Or worst case scenario, you can copy the data but you have to put in lot effort to ensure they remain in sync.

Most of the choices are not straight forward and there will be trade offs that you need to take call on.